# Perl pattern matching issue while validating

Tags: perl

I have perl script which checks the SVN Log and extract the commit message and validate for the commit message format as below :

```
TAL: 12345, JIRA: QC-11115, BBC: ACR-12334 
Program: Some definite name
Reviewer: committer name or his employee ID (5digits) 
Description: Some relevant description
```

OR

```
 JIRA: ABC-123 
 Program: Some definite name 
 Reviewer: committer name or his employee ID (5digits) 
 Description: Some relevant description:
 - Some more relevant description
 - Much relevant description
```

comments are extracted and stored in an array - **@my_comments** and accessed like below

```
        if (($my_comments[$j] =~/(((JIRA|TAL|BBC):\s{0,2}[A-Za-z0-9-]{4,15},{0,1}\s{0,2}){1,5})\nProgram:\s{0,2}[A-Za-z]{3,20}\nReviewer:\s{0,2}[A-Za-z0-9\s]{4,40}\nDescription:\s{0,2}[A-Za-z0-9\s].*/))

    {       print "GOOD";
            $compliance = "YES";
    }
    else
    {       print "FAILED";
            $compliance = "NO";
    }
push @my_Compliance,$compliance;
.....
```

Also , FYR

```
print "ARRAY COMMENTS:$my_comments[$j]\n";
```

gave output like below as expected

```
TAL: 12345, JIRA: QC-11115, BBC: ACR-12334
Program: Some definite name
Reviewer: committer name or his employee ID (5digits)
Description: Some relevant description
```

So , I suspect issue is with the my pattern matching. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Program:\s{0,2}[A-Za-z]{3,20}` pattern does not allow spaces while your input sample `Program: Some definite name` has some. Adding spaces into the pattern should solve the issue: https://regex101.com/r/iA8kE9/1.

Comment: Thank you , that fixed the issue.